# Aplicación guarda datos en unos dispositivos y en otros no

Tags: android, android-studio

Hice aplicación de dietas que he subido al *Google Play*, en la cual introduces tus datos en un formulario y este los tiene que guardar en una base de datos y mostrarte la dieta personalizada. En todos los dispositivos físicos y emuladores que he probado me funciona correctamente. El problema es que **no guarda los datos**.

Estas son las tres clases que manejan la base de datos:

```
package database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "basededatos";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.SQL_CREATE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ExtructuraDbGrafico.ExDbGrafico.SQL_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.SQL_DELETE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(ExtructuraDbGrafico.ExDbGrafico.SQL_DELETE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
```

---

```
package database;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;


public class ExtructuraDb {
    public ExtructuraDb() {
    }
    public static abstract class Extructura implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "perfil";
    public static final String C_GENERO = "genero";
    public static final String C_PESO = "peso";
    public static final String C_ALTURA = "altura";
    public static final String C_EDAD = "edad";
    public static final String C_ACTIVIDAD = "actividad";
    public static final String C_TIPO_DIETA = "tipoDieta";

    private static final String COMA = ",";
    private static final String TEXT = " TEXT";

    public final static String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            C_GENERO + TEXT + COMA + C_ACTIVIDAD + TEXT + COMA + C_TIPO_DIETA + TEXT + COMA +
            C_PESO + TEXT + COMA + C_ALTURA + TEXT + COMA + C_EDAD + TEXT + ")";

    public static final String SQL_DELETE = "DROP IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}
```

---

```
package database;

import java.net.PortUnreachableException;


public class ExtructuraDbGrafico {

    public ExtructuraDbGrafico() {
    }

    public static abstract class ExDbGrafico{

        public static final String ID = "id";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "grafico";
        public static final String PESO = "peso";
        public static final String FECHA = "fecha";

        private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
        private static final String COMA = ",";
        private static final String PRIMARY_KEY = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";

        protected static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + ExDbGrafico.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                ExDbGrafico.ID + ExDbGrafico.PRIMARY_KEY + COMA +
                ExDbGrafico.PESO + ExDbGrafico.TEXT_TYPE + COMA +
                ExDbGrafico.FECHA+ ExDbGrafico.TEXT_TYPE + ")";
        protected static final String SQL_DELETE =
                "DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + ExDbGrafico.TABLE_NAME;

    }
}
```

---

Esta es la actividad que se encarga del formulario de la base de datos para guardarlos:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import adaptadores.RecyclerDietaAdapter;
import database.DbHelper;
import database.ExtructuraDb;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class Perfil_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
       public  static int verdad = 0;
        public  static int mentira = 2;
        Snackbar snackbar;
        private Button guardar;

    private String TAG = "SQLite";
    private ImageView img_perfil;
    private Spinner spin, spin_tipo_dieta;
    private RadioButton radioHombre, radioMujer;
    String tipoDieta = "";
    String genero = "";

    String actividad = "";
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private TextInputEditText tiet_peso,tiet_altura,tiet_edad;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil_activity);

        guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_guardar);
        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                guardar(view);
            }
        });
        tiet_peso = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.tiet_peso);
        tiet_altura = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.tiet_altura);
        tiet_edad = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.tiet_edad);

        radioHombre = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_masculino);
        radioMujer = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_femenino);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_id);



        spin_tipo_dieta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_tipo_dieta);

       spin_tipo_dieta.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               switch (i){
                   case 0:


                       tipoDieta = "-20";
                       break;

                   case 1:
                       tipoDieta = "20";
                       break;

                   case 2:
                       tipoDieta = "0";
                       break;
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       });
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_actividad);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        actividad = "1.2";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        actividad = "1.375";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        actividad = "1.55";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        actividad = "1.725";
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        actividad = "1.9";
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                //El tft deve de ser igual al que queramos utilizar
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Abel-Regular.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );

        img_perfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_perfil);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.ic_perfil)
                .into(img_perfil);


    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    public void fabAtras (View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(Perfil_activity.this, MainActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("mentira",mentira);
        finish();
    }
    public void spinner (){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Actividades,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void guardar (View view) {
      // int altura = Integer.parseInt(tiet_altura.getText().toString());


        String altura = tiet_altura.getText().toString();
        String peso = tiet_peso.getText().toString();
        String edad = tiet_edad.getText().toString();
        String genero1 = genero.toString();
        String actividad1 = actividad.toString();
        String tipoDieta1 = tipoDieta.toString();

        String uno = "uno";




        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(altura)|TextUtils.isEmpty(peso) | TextUtils.isEmpty(edad) | TextUtils.isEmpty(genero1) ){

            snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Faltan datos por introducir",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Perfil_activity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));
            snackbar.show();
            verdad = 2;
            Intent i = new Intent(Perfil_activity.this, MainActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("verdad",verdad);
            //Ocultar teclado
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }else{
            try {
                DbHelper admin = new DbHelper(this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();


                db.delete(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.TABLE_NAME,null,null);

                    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_GENERO, genero1);
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_ACTIVIDAD,actividad1);
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_TIPO_DIETA,tipoDieta1);
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_ALTURA,altura);
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_PESO,peso);
                    valores.put(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.C_EDAD,edad);
                    db.insert(ExtructuraDb.Extructura.TABLE_NAME,null,valores);
                    db.close();
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Perfil guardado",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Perfil_activity.this,R.color.colorPrimary));
                snackbar.show();
                verdad = 1;
                Intent i = new Intent(Perfil_activity.this, MainActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("verdad",verdad);
                //Ocultar teclado
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(Perfil_activity.this,"Error: ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            };
        }

    }

  public void checkHombre (View view) {

      //Si un radiobutton esta marcado el otro se desmarca

      switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.radio_masculino:

              radioMujer.setChecked(false);
              genero = "5";

              break;
          case R.id.radio_femenino:

              radioHombre.setChecked(false);
              genero = "-161";

              break;
      }
  }
}
```

---

Esta es la actividad que se encarga de mostrar los datos de la base de datos:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adaptadores.RecyclerDietaAdapter;
import adaptadores.RecyclerHorizontalAdapter;
import database.DbHelper;
import database.ExtructuraDb;
import datos.DatosRecyclerDieta;

public class Dieta_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img_cabecera;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewDesayuno,recyclerViewAlmuerzo,recycladorComida,recycladorMerienda,recycladorCena;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dieta_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(Dieta_activity.this);

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + ExtructuraDb.Extructura.TABLE_NAME,null);

                if (fila.moveToFirst()){
                    float num;
                    int generoD = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(0));
                    float actividad = Float.parseFloat(fila.getString(1));
                    int tipoDieta = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(2));
                    float peso = Float.parseFloat(fila.getString(3));
                    int altura = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(4));
                    int edad = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(5));
                    float basal = (float) ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * altura) - (5 * edad) + generoD);
                    float calorias = basal * actividad ;
                    float caloriasTotal = calorias * tipoDieta / 100 + calorias;
                   // int total = (int) caloriasTotal;
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
                    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

                    String pan = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/45));
                    String avena = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/53));
                    String totalString = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal));
                    String quesoFresco = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/45));
                    String jamonHuevo = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/53));
                    String patata = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/8));
                    String carnePescado = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/13));
                    String pasta = String.valueOf(df.format(caloriasTotal/27));

                    Intent i = new Intent(Dieta_activity.this,Main_Activity_Detalle_Dieta.class);

                    i.putExtra("Pan",pan);
                    i.putExtra("Avena",avena);
                    i.putExtra("Quesofresco",quesoFresco);
                    i.putExtra("Patata",patata);
                    i.putExtra("CarnePescado",carnePescado);
                    i.putExtra("Pasta",pasta);
                    startActivity(i);


                }

                }
        });

      establecer();
      img_cabecera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_cabecera);
        Glide.with(this).
                load(R.drawable.img_dietaequilibrada).
                centerCrop().
                into(img_cabecera);


    }
    public void establecer() {

        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + ExtructuraDb.Extructura.TABLE_NAME,null);

        if (fila.moveToFirst()){
            float num;
            int generoD = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(0));
            float actividad = Float.parseFloat(fila.getString(1));
            int tipoDieta = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(2));
            float peso = Float.parseFloat(fila.getString(3));
            int altura = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(4));
            int edad = Integer.parseInt(fila.getString(5));
            int basal = (int) ((10 * peso) + (6.25 * altura) - (5 * edad) + generoD);
            float calorias = basal * actividad ;
            float caloriasTotal = calorias * tipoDieta / 100 + calorias;
            int total = (int) caloriasTotal;
            String pan = String.valueOf(total/45);
            String avena = String.valueOf(total/53);
            String quesoFresco = String.valueOf(total/45);
            String jamonHuevo = String.valueOf(total/53);
            String patata = String.valueOf(total/8);
            String carnePescado = String.valueOf(total/13);
            String pasta = String.valueOf(total/27);
            String mitadMedidaAvena = String.valueOf(total/106);
            String mitadCarnePescado = String.valueOf(total/26);




            List items = new ArrayList();
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_desayuno,"Opción 1.","Vaso de leche desnatada.","("+ pan +")gr de pan integral con mermelada light."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_yogurt_avena,"Opción 2.", "Yogur desnatado con ("+ avena +") gr de avena.","Una pieza de fruta."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_cafe,"Opción 3.","Té o café.", "(" + pan + ")gr de pan integral con ("+ quesoFresco +")gr de queso fresco."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_jamon_cocido,"Opción 4.","Vaso de zumo.","(" + pan + ")gr de pan integral con jamón cocido, pavo o jamón."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_huevo_revulelto,"Opción 5","Huevo revuelto con " + "(" + jamonHuevo + ")gr de jamón cocido","Zumo de fruta o fruta."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_leche_avena,"Opción 6.","Leche sola o con (" + avena + ")gr de avena."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_smootie,"Opción 7","Smothie quemagrasas:","\n. 1 Taza de té verde\n. 1 Rodaja de piña natural\n. ("+ mitadMedidaAvena +
                    ")+ gr de avena\n. ("+ mitadMedidaAvena + ")gr de semillas de lino."));
            items.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_tostadanaranja,"Opción 8","Zumo de naranja natural.","Tostada integral con atún en lata sin aceite."));

            recyclerViewDesayuno = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador_desayuno);
            recyclerViewDesayuno.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewDesayuno.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            recyclerViewDesayuno.setAdapter(new RecyclerHorizontalAdapter(items,Dieta_activity.this));

            List itemsAlmuerzo = new ArrayList();

            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_jamon,"Opción 1.","(" + pan + ")gr de pan con jamón, jamón cocido, pavo."));
            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_peque_a_ensalada,"Opción 2","Ensalada pequeña de atún en agua, máximo dos cucharadas de aceite."));

            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_quesofresco,"Opción 3.","(" + quesoFresco + ")gr de queso fresco light con mermelada light."));
            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_zumo_frutos_secos,"Opcion 4.","Zumo natural.","Medio puñado de frutos secos."));
            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_ensaladapollo,"Opción 5", "Ensalada pequeña con (" + mitadCarnePescado + ")gr de pollo a la plancha."));
            itemsAlmuerzo.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_pimientos_piquillo,"Opción 6","Pimientos de piquillo (3 maximo) rellenos de cebolla, pimiento y atun."));
            recyclerViewAlmuerzo = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador_almuerzo);
            recyclerViewAlmuerzo.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewAlmuerzo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            recyclerViewAlmuerzo.setAdapter(new RecyclerHorizontalAdapter(itemsAlmuerzo,Dieta_activity.this));

            List itemsComida = new ArrayList();

            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_pure_verduras,"Opción 1.","Purè de verduras (máximo " + patata + ")gr de patata.","Pollo (" + carnePescado + ")gr.",
                    "Fruta"));
            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_spagetis,"Opcion 2.","Pasta (" + pasta +")gr con tomate y carne picada (" + carnePescado + ")gr.","Fruta."));
            itemsComida.add((new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_arroz_jamon,"Opcion 3.","Ensalada.","Arroz (" + pasta + ")gr con jamón (" + carnePescado + ")gr.", "Fruta.")));
            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_lentejas_verduras,"Opcion 4.","Lentejas (" + pasta + ")gr con verduras.", "Pechuga de pollo (" + carnePescado + ")gr.","Fruta"));
            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_fideos,"Opción 5.","Sopa de fideos " + pasta + ")gr.","Pescado (" + carnePescado + ")gr.","Fruta"));
            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_guisado,"Opción 6.","Guisado de ternera (" + carnePescado + "gr con patatas (" + patata + ")gr y verduras.","Fruta"));
            itemsComida.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_pechuga,"Opción 7","Pechuga de pollo (" + carnePescado + ")gr al horno con verduras y patata (" + patata + ").","Fruta."));

            recycladorComida = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador_comida);
            recycladorComida.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycladorComida.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            recycladorComida.setAdapter(new RecyclerHorizontalAdapter(itemsComida,this));

            List itemsMerienda = new ArrayList();

            itemsMerienda.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_yogurt_natural,"Opción 1.", "Yogur natural.","Fruta."));
            itemsMerienda.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_leche_avena2,"Opción 2.","Vaso de leche con ("+ avena + ")gr de avena"));
            itemsMerienda.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_jamon,"Opción 3.","(" + pan + ")gr de pan con jamón, jamón cocido, pavo con tomate."));
            itemsMerienda.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_macedonia,"Opción 4.","Macedonia de frutas."));
            itemsMerienda.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_cafe_leche,"Opción 5.","Café con leche desnatada y dos galletas bajas en calorías. "));

            recycladorMerienda = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador_merienda);
            recycladorMerienda.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycladorMerienda.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            recycladorMerienda.setAdapter(new RecyclerHorizontalAdapter(itemsMerienda,this));

            List itemsCena = new ArrayList();

            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_verduras,"Opción 1.","Verduras hervidas o plancha (Sin patata)","Mero (" + carnePescado + ")gr.","Yogur desnatado."));
            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_pavo,"Opción 2.","Filete de pavo (" + carnePescado + ")gr con verduras plancha.","Yogur desnatado."));
            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_pechuga_naranja,"Opción 3.","Pechuga (" + carnePescado + ")gr al horno con verduras.","Yogur desnatado."));
            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_hamburguesa,"Opción 4.","Hamburguesa de pollo con pimientos y cebolla a la plancha.","Yogur desnatado."));
            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_ensalada,"Opción 5.","Ensalada con pollo (" + carnePescado + ")gr o atún en agua.","Yogur desnatado."));
            itemsCena.add(new DatosRecyclerDieta(R.drawable.img_sepia,"Opcion 6.","Sepia o pota de calamar plancha (" + carnePescado + ")gr con setas", "Yogur desnatado."));

            recycladorCena = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.reciclador_cena);
            recycladorCena.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycladorCena.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            recycladorCena.setAdapter(new RecyclerHorizontalAdapter(itemsCena,this));






        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

---

Seguramente contendrá fallos, mi nivel de programación aún es básico, cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida, esta es la aplicación por si podéis descargarla para ver si os falla o no, [apk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ricesa.dieta)

Comment: ¿El usuario debe aceptar algún permiso para guardar esos datos? Quizás al no permitir acceso a su tarjeta externa o algo parecido esté ocurriendo esto

Comment: No, no hay ningun tipo de permiso que aceptar, lo que no entiendo es como a mi me funciona en todos  los dispositivos y emuladores y a muchos usuarios no.

Answer (score 0):

hay que cerrar el cursor: `fila.close();` o bien `return fila;` Ademas de agregar `if (fila != null){` antes de `if (fila.moveToFirst()){`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, se me olvido pornerlo, ¿Crees que eso solucionara que funcione en un unos dispositivos y en otros no?